# Malformed Collection Error

Tags: ant, iis-7, appcmd

Moving on from the first issue I reported here :
[Running an OS command using apache-ant to IIS config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627303/iis-config-via-ant)

I am trying to run the second part of the IIS config.

```
  <exec executable="cmd.exe" dir="C:/Windows/System32/inetsrv" 
    failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/c appcmd set config /section:handlers 
 /[name=&apos;ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-
    4.0&apos;].verb:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,CONNECT"/>
    </exec>
```

I have no double quotes in this line, and I am using apos; to indicate my single quotes. However I'm getting the following error which Im struggling to find an explanation for :

confIIS:

```
[echo] Configuring IIS
[exec] ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is 
[@position,name='value',name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is 
optional, and be '@start', '@end', or
@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )
```

quick Update :
I've tried dbl quotes but no luck. I've done some more digging and the issue is that the single quotes are being dropped.
If I run the cmd line in the dos prompt  without the single quotes it fails in the same way.
cmd line :

```
appcmd set config /section:handlers  /[name='ExtensionlessUrlHandler-
Integrated-4.0'].verb:GET
```

Ant script (debug) output

```
[exec] 'appcmd'
[exec] 'set'
[exec] 'config'
[exec] '/section:handlers'
[exec] '/[name=ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-
4.0].verb:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,CONNECT'
[exec]
[exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
[exec] not part of the command.
ute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'cmd.exe' with arguments:
```

Comment: See if this helps - https://forums.iis.net/t/1164076.aspx?Configuring+defaultDocument+property+via+appcmd

Comment: I've done smoe more digging and it's dropping the single quotes for some reason (see above)

Comment: ok, fixed it !
quotes were placed wrong :)